# React Native - Can't display the Data in other screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

What I want to achieve is display the datas in other screen or another component with React Redux. I'm using the latest version of React Redux and Redux.

> My problem is every time I want to display the data, or when I press the button (TouchableOpacity) in EventCreator.js it doesn't display. I tried to check all of my codes but I don't see any typo or any wrong codes.

Feel free to ask for more of my codes. Thank you!

> UPDATE: I tried all codes to my another new project, but with RNNV1. So it might be some new codes for RNNv2 that is related to React Redux to change. I prefer to all viewers to focus check my codes about RNNv2 connected to React Redux. Thank you!

These are my codes:

App.js, all my Registered Screens.

```
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
import React from 'react';

//Screens
import AuthScreen from './src/screens/Auth/Auth';
import EventMap from './src/screens/Map/Map';
import EventCreator from './src/screens/EventCreator/EventCreator';
import EventHome from './src/screens/Home/Home';
import EventPushScreen from './src/screens/EventPushScreen/EventPushSc';

//Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

//Register Screens
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux("Event.AuthScreen", () => AuthScreen);
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux("Event.Map", () => EventMap);
Navigation.registerComponent("EventCreator", () => (props) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <EventCreator {...props}/>
  </Provider>
), () => EventCreator);
Navigation.registerComponent("EventHome", () => (props) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <EventHome {...props}/>
  </Provider>
), () => EventHome);



//Start A App
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      stack: {
        children: [{
          component: {
            name: "Event.AuthScreen",
          }
        }],
        options: {
          topBar: {
            title: {
              text: 'Welcome',
              alignment: 'center'
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
  });
});
```

This is my 1st Screen where the TextInput and Button (TouchableOpacity) is.
EventCreator.js

```
import EventInput from '../../components/EventInput';

class EventCreator extends Component {

eventAddedHandler = (eventName) => {
  this.props.onAddEvent(eventName);
};

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <EventInput onEventAdded={this.eventAddedHandler}/>
  </View>
);
}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onAddEvent: (eventName) => dispatch(addEvent(eventName))
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(EventCreator);
```

EventInput.js, This is my Component that is connected to EventCreate.js

```
class EventInput extends Component {
state = {
  eventName: ""
};

eventNameChangedHandler = (val) => {
this.setState({
  eventName: val
});
};

eventSubmitHandler = () => {
  if (this.state.eventName.trim() === "") {
    return;
  }

this.props.onEventAdded(this.state.eventName);
};

render () {
return (
  <View style={styles.inputAndButtonContainer}>
    <TextInput
      placeholder="Create your event"
      value={this.state.eventName}
      onChangeText={this.eventNameChangedHandler}
      style={styles.textInputContainer}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.eventSubmitHandler}>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>Add</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
}
};
```

Home.js, this is where I want to display may Data or the FlatList.

```
class Home extends Component {

eventSelectedHandler = key => {
  const selEvent = this.props.events.find(event => {
    return event.key === key;
  });
  Navigation.push("EventHomeStack", {
    component: {
      name: "EventPushScreen",
      passProps: {
        selectedEvent: selEvent
      },
      options: {
        topBar: {
          title: {
            text: selEvent.name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <EventList 
        events={this.props.events}
        onItemSelected={this.eventSelectedHandler}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    events: state.events.events
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

EventList.js, another Component connected to Home.js

```
import ListItem from './ListItem';

const eventList = (props) => {
  return (
    <FlatList 
      style={styles.listContainer}
      data={props.events}
      renderItem={(info) => (
        <ListItem
          eventName={info.item.name}
          eventImage={info.item.image}
          onItemPressed={() => props.onItemSelected(info.item.key)}
        />
      )}
    />
 );
 };

export default eventList;
```

listItem.js, another Component connected to EventList.js

```
const listItem = (props) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onItemPressed}>
    <View style={styles.listItem}>
      <Image resizeMode="cover" source={props.eventImage} style={styles.eventImage}/>
      <Text>
         {props.eventName}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 );

 export default listItem;
```

events.js (reducer)

```
import {ADD_EVENT, DELETE_EVENT} from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  events: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_EVENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        events: state.events.concat({
          key:  `${Math.random()}`, 
          name: action.eventName,
          image: {
            uri: "https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4096/4744241983_34023bf303_b.jpg"
          }
        })
      };

case DELETE_EVENT:
  return {
    ...state,
    events: state.events.filter(event => {
      return event.key !== action.eventKey;
    })
  };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: If you log what a reducer ADD_EVENT returns in your reducer, do you get the pushed data in your events array  every time you click the 'Add' button?
`case ADD_EVENT:
      const newState = {
        ...state,
        events: state.events.concat({
          key:  Math.random(), 
          name: action.eventName,
          image: {
            uri: "https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4096/4744241983_34023bf303_b.jpg"
          }
        });
       console.log(newState);
       return newState;
      };
`

Comment: I get the State and only 1 data which is the eventName (on what I type in TextInput). But overall, nothing is displaying

Comment: Basically make some more debugging logs like:
`import ListItem from './ListItem';

const eventList = (props) => { console.log("This should be called everytime 'add' is clicked. whats here?", props);
  return (...`

Comment: Just a reminder that I'm using the RNNv2, and the latest React Redux and Redux. There might be some changes about the codes both library that I do now know. Thank you.

Comment: I will try it. Wait a minute.

Comment: My React Native Debugger is connected to my App and also the the Redux. Is there something you want to know?

Comment: For the reply for your 2nd comment. This what shows in my debugger, "Object {events: Array(0)}, events: Array(0)

Comment: When does that show in your debugger? I am asking since my first comment about logging the changes in your state, or every time the 'Add' event is triggered, so you need to do that and share what you are getting

Comment: It shows up when I press the "Add" button. Then the only data I get is the eventName and also the key.

Comment: I think the state is working properly, the issue might be when dispatching the action.